# Installing tensorflow, getting error 'pip3' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow, artificial-intelligence

I am trying to install tensorflow for their image recognition program thing, but I get the error in the title, it does work when i go to C:\Users\Diederik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts, and type pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow there, but I am not sure if that is how I am supposed to do it, since I tried that before and I got errors while running the classify_image.py, so I thought maybe I should try it the way tensorflow told me to, but that didn't work, Please help me, I am happy to provide any extra information you need. I am on windows 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `./pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow` from that directory. I think on windows, you need to be explicit that the command is in your working directory. Alternatively you could try

`C:\Users\Diederik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts\pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow`. That's how I do it on my windoze machine.

Comment: Alright, thanks, I did that and it's working, have you used the tensorflow image recognition program? Asking so if I have another problem I could come to you for help.

Comment: If you have used the image recognition program before, could you help me out with this? I tried running classify_image.py, but I get this error:
if you have done it before, do you know how I fix this? I tried to run the classify_image.py but I got this error:

`import tensorflow as tf
  File "C:\Users\Diederik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.python'
`

Comment: If I solved your original issue of getting pip3 working, can you mark this question solved?